# Excel Formula not accepted but no reason for error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

I have a if formula with a number of criterias it has to match.

When I have shortened the formula down it works from beyond - IF(LEFT(A6,1)="2"

but there are no reasons it should error at this point? Any help?

```
=IF(LEFT(A6,2)="10","Area 1",IF(LEFT(A6,2)="12","Area 2",IF(LEFT(A6,2)="13","Area 3",IF(LEFT(A6,2)="14","Area 4",IF(LEFT(A6,2)="15","Area 5",IF(LEFT(A6,2)="16","Area 6",IF(LEFT(A6,2)="17","Area 7",IF(LEFT(A6,1)="2","Bulk",IF(LEFT(A6,1)="4","Intl",IF(LEFT(A6,2)="7","CGCC","Ad-Hoc"))))))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try combining `IF` and `VLOOKUP`.

```
=IF(LEFT(A6,1)="4","Intl",IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A6,2),{"7","CGCC";"10","Area 1";"12","Area 2";"13","Area 3";"14","Area 4";"15","Area 5";"16","Area 6";"17","Area 7"},2,FALSE)),"Ad-Hoc",VLOOKUP(LEFT(A6,2),{"7","CGCC";"10","Area 1";"12","Area 2";"13","Area 3";"14","Area 4";"15","Area 5";"16","Area 6";"17","Area 7"},2,FALSE)))
```

I embedded the array in the formula but you can prepare a table (assume `G1:H7`) like this:

[image]

and then use the `VLOOKUP` with the reference:

```
=IF(LEFT(A6,1)="4","Intl",IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A6,2),G1:H7,2,FALSE)),"Ad-Hoc",VLOOKUP(LEFT(A6,2),G1:H7,2,FALSE)))
```

`IFNA` or `IFERROR` could also be used but they are not available in Excel 2003.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire formula could be shortened to 2 VLOOKUP functions, by putting your data into a table, with your ID column on, say, column A of sheet2, and your results column on column B of sheet2. This would look as follows:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A6,2),'Sheet2'!A:B,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A6),'Sheet2'!A:B,2,0),"Ad Hoc"))
```

What this does is: first try to match the left 2 characters in A6 to one of your ID's in column A in sheet2. If that creates an error, it tries to match the left 1 character in A6 to one of your ID's in column A of sheet2. Either way, it returns the matching value in column B of sheet2. If no match is found, it returns "Ad Hoc".